# Methods like ord and chr from Python

Tags: java, python, converters

Do you know any functions that would preform the same as `ord` and `chr` from Python in Java.

Python docs on them.

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr

I've experienced manually but seem to get so many errors. This would need to work with `Strings` not just `char`. Figured I would see if there was a function to do it pre-built.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can cast:

```
c = (char) n;

n = (int) c;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try implementing like you've suggested and get back to you if I encounter an error if you don't mind

Comment: Note that the first of the above does **NOT** check if `n` overflows a `char`, unlike `chr(..)` in Python.

Comment: An example of the overflow is `chr(119070)` which is a completely different character than `(char)119070`.