# java switch statement with empty string

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

I have to sort objects based on their area, leftborder or lowerborder. When I want to sort them on their left- or lower border I have to say sort x and sort y. When I want to sort by area I need to say just sort. I was trying to do this via a switch method but I don't know how you can use a switch method that has an empty string in it. This is what I was trying to do:

```
case "sort":
  System.out.println("On what do you want to sort?");
  String choice = scanner.nextLine();
  switch (choice) {
    case "x":
      Arrays.sort(g, 0, lastPos, new Comparator < Geometric > () {
        @Override
        public int compare(Geometric o1, Geometric o2) {
          if (o1.leftBorder() < o2.leftBorder()) {
            return -1;
          } else if (o1.leftBorder() > o2.leftBorder()) {
            return 1;
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
        }

      });
      break;
    case "y":
      Arrays.sort(g, 0, lastPos, new Comparator < Geometric > () {
        @Override
        public int compare(Geometric o1, Geometric o2) {
          if (o1.bottomBorder() < o2.bottomBorder()) {
            return -1;
          } else if (o1.bottomBorder() > o2.bottomBorder()) {
            return 1;
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
        }

      });
      break;
    case (""):
      Arrays.sort(g, 0, lastPos, new Comparator < Geometric > () {
        @Override
        public int compare(Geometric o1, Geometric o2) {
          if (o1.area() < o2.area()) {
            return -1;
          } else if (o1.area() > o2.area()) {
            return 1;
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
        }

      });
      break;
    default:
      System.out.println("test1");
  }
```

Comment: Code is a bit messy, but the empty string switch branch is okay.

Comment: Switch is ok though i'd remove the parentheses. So what is your real problem - some error, some odd behavior or ....?

Comment: For a better code, I would suggest using a Enum and writing the method inside it

Comment: Maybe you could convert `choice` to char. Then cast it to an int and compare the character code. Perhaps you are getting something like Carriage Return or newline instead.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20250062/495157

Answer (score 0):

The are better way to order your code (say using a factory for the Comparator) but just to stick to your code I think an ENUM would solve your problem.

```
public enum CHOICES {
    X, Y, AREA
}

private static CHOICES getChoice(String choice) {
    if (choice == null || choice.trim().length() == 0) {
        return CHOICES.AREA; 
    }
    try {
        return CHOICES.valueOf(choice.toUpperCase());   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // instead to check the value, 
        // if the input fir on, if not just catch the exception and return null
        return null;
    }       
}
```

Then you can replace your switch like below

```
        //String choice = scanner.nextLine();
    CHOICES choice = getChoice(scanner.nextLine());     
    switch (choice) {       
    case X:
        //sort by X
        break;
    case Y:
        //sort by Y
        break;
    case AREA:
        //sort by area
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("test1");
    }
```